# How to toggle between two different layouts for an ExpandableListView childView?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, expandablelistview, android-adapter

I finally have my `ExpandableListView` working (thanks to SO), but now I want to be able to toggle between two different childViews whenever I (short) click on a child item.

I have this snippet for the `setOnChildClickListener`, which currently resides in the `onCreate` section. I assume I have to move this to within the `BaseExpandableListAdapter` in order to be able to toggle the layout of the childView (or can I do this from within `onCreate`?)

maybe a picture can illustrate it best: If I click on the 'PPLT' child, I want it to expand to approx. double height and and more info (according to a different child xml layout file)

```
 expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.StockExpandList);

 expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(PortfolioView.this, SubcategoryList, subgroupCollection);
 expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);

 expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

     public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, 
        View v,int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

          final String selected = (String) expListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          return true;
     }
});
```

I'm probably showing my ignorance on how a basic listview adapter works, but I assume this is where I add a condition that decides whether to use the default child_item layout or the other one I want to show up when I click on it (e.g. called child_expanded_item since it's supposed to be larger with more info in it)

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int    
       childPosition,boolean isLastChild,View childView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
   LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

   if (childView == null) {
       childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
   }
}
```

Or do I go crazy and do a nested `ExpandableListView`?

[image]

Comment: In getChildView() method based on position you can change the layout for each child.

Comment: I want it based on a click on that child